# How to resolve blazor code error CS1061 'GroupsService' does not contain a definition for 'userobj'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im trying to call separate objects from different classes in a blazor page and I get the error message below

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'GroupsService' does not contain a definition for 'userobj' and no accessible extension method 'userobj' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupsService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BlazorServeApp  C:\Users\User\source\repos\BlazorServeApp\BlazorServeApp\Pages\GroupData.razor  83  Active

```
@page "/groupdata"
@using BlazorServeApp.Data
@using BlazorServeApp.Models
@using BlazorServeApp.Services
@inherits OwningComponentBase<GroupsService>


<h3>Group Data In Dropdown List</h3>







<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="Imei" class="control-label">IMEI *</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="User" class="control-label">User *</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="imei" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" onchange="">
            <option value="">-- Select User --</option>
            @*@if (usrobj != null)
        {
            @foreach (var item in usrobj)
            {
                <option value="@usrobj.Email">@usrobj.Email</option>

            }
        }*@
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top:50px">

</div> <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="Group" class="control-label">Group *</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="Authorization" class="control-label">Authorization *</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="authorization" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" onchange="">
            <option value="">-- Select Group --</option>
            @*@if (grobj != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in grobj)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.grobj">@item.grobj</option>

                    }
                }*@
        </select>
    </div>
</div>



@code {

    List<GroupsClass> grobj;
    List<UserClass> usrobj;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //base.OnInitialized();
        grobj = Service.groupsobj();
        usrobj = Service.userobj();
    }
}
```

Comment: So which line is `GroupData.razor 83`?  It might help (just a little)!  The error suggests that the class `GroupService` does not contain a public method `userobj()`.  Does it?

Comment: Can you share your `GroupService`?